# Issues importing PST into Archive Mailbox Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-2013, mailbox, import

I've completed a successful mailbox import request into the archive mailbox for a particular user. There are no errors to speak of and the size of the archive mailbox has grown to the expected size after import (approximately 6GB).

However, in OWA I can't see any of the mail folders inside the archive mailbox, only Deleted Items and RSS feeds folders. However if I run some cmdlets to list the contents of the Archive Mailbox\Inbox folder in the Exchange Shell, the full list of subfolders will come up.

If I do a mail item search on the archive mailbox, emails from those individual folders appear  as search results! I just can't see the folders in the navigation pane and hence cannot browse any of my old emails.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a folder in the archive and importing directly into that folder seemed to resolve the issue. The subfolders in the PST file now appear in the archive.

Answer (score 2):

In my company access to Archived PST files via OWA is unavailable so I'd always assumed that it was generally impossible under the available Exchange environments. However, I found this [Technet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979800(v=exchg.150).aspx) that states that as long as you're using at least exchange 2010 or an updated version of 2007 you should be able to see them. Apparently they're called "Online Archives".

According to [this other article](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/523) you must have the professional plus licensing for the outlook client and version 2007-2013, not even standard is  enough. Also, apparently:

> The use of the Personal Archive (or In-Place Archive) function in Exchange 2010 or Exchange 2013 requires an additional Enterprise Client Access License (CAL).

So it might be the case that all of this just comes down to licensing.

Comment: It isn't a license issue. The archive mailbox is fully functional and the mail items are searchable, just that the folders are not visible.

Comment: @atomicharri I thought the issue was seeing the files in the archive, but seeing the migrated archive in OWA

Answer (score 0):

This example imports a .pst file into anne.dunn archive folder. The TargetRootFolder isn't specified; therefore, content is merged under existing folders and new folders are created if they don't already exist in the target folder structure.

```
New-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox "anne.dunn" -IsArchive -FilePath "\\sharepathname\Anne.Dunn_LEG.pst"  -TargetRootFolder /
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607310%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx